# ArcGIS Server Module - Service Manifest XML

Tags: python, web-service, rest

I'm trying to access the service manifest XML (the same that appears via "https://..../arcgis/admin/services/folder/.../iteminfo/manifest/manifest.xml" through the arcgis.gis.server module.

I've followed the docos here: https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.server.html#service

The JSON I can reach but it hides the Oracle DB schema name. Trying to get the XML one gives the error 'AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'service_manifest'

Here is an example of my script  - any advice?

```
server = Server(url="https://.../arcgis/admin", username= r"u", password = r"pw")
services = server.services
for x in services.list(folder='folder1'):
     service_name = x.iteminformation.properties['name']
     service_manifest = x.iteminformation.manifest         #this works fine but hides the oracle DB schema name
     service_manifest_xml = x.service_manifest(file_type='xml')    #this gets the error AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'service_manifest
```

Comment: The schema name *shoudn't* be part of the  service properties, much the way you shouldn't share the first 12 digits of your credit card number.

Comment: Accessing the manifest xml via `manifest/manifest.xml` is an undocumented part of  the ArcGIS REST API for Server Administration, and it isn't supported in the ArcGIS API for Python.  You are going to have to roll your own HTTP requests to use that undocumented feature of the API.